# c++ initializing char array member of class

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

in my c++ project I have class with two members. the char array member I have problems with.

```
class frame_message
{
public:
    explicit frame_message(const unsigned int id, const char data[]) :id_(id), data_{ *data }{};
    // only the first char 'a' is copied to `data_`
    char* get_data() { return data_; };
    void get_data(char** data) { *data = data_; };
private:
    unsigned int id_; char data_[8];
};
```

now from main method I want to send another char array used to initialize the class array.

```
main
{
char data[8]={'a','b','c'} // indexs 3 to 7 are '\0'
char data2[8];
char data3[8];
frame_message myMessage(0xF004,data); // the data is passed as "abc"
data2 = myMessage.get_data(); // analysis error
myMessage.get_data(&data3); // runtime exception
}
```

How should I initialize the private member of class with exactly the data array send to constructor?

also for for `get_data` functions what data type should be passed?

p.s. I am new in c/c++ and yet get confused in pointers, references and specially `char` and `char*`

Comment: `main` is missing parameter list and return type. There does not seem to be any reason to use a fixed-size C-style array here. Just use `std::string` and you won't have any of your problems.

Comment: You've got two methods called get_data when it looks like the second one should be called set_data ?

Comment: Keep in mind, in your case *data = 'a' when you probably want a copy of the array. There are 2 ways to do this, you can just give it the address of data - i.e. lose the * in your constructor or do a memcpy or similar if you want to also keep the data in the main for later use. if you just give it the address then modifying it in one place will also modify other. Edit: i just noticed you used static arrays so just assigning the address would not work - you need to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the constructor, it would be a good idea to pass a length parameter as well because you can accept only up to 8 bytes.
Then, if your length is <= 8 :

```
memcpy(data_, data, length)
```

Same thing in your parameterized get_data, so it would be:

```
memcpy(*data, data_, 8) /* Assuming that they provide long enough array. */
```

It is good practice when dealing with arrays to always include length, and when dealing with pointers to check if they are NULL - I'll leave this to you.
The reason you were getting errors is because you cannot assign a pointer to a statically declared array - it has a fixed address, you can only change the content.